# Input for Hidden Markov Model-based speech recognition program

Tags: c++, speech-recognition, hidden-markov-models

I am going to build a speech recognition program based on Hidden Markov Model. Unfortunately, I don't know how to get an input sound sequence, and, well, work with it. Can anyone tell me what is the general approach for reading values from a sound file format (i.e. .wav, .mp3, etc)and slicing a soundtrack into pieces in C++?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links/libs#Audio

Comment: It is better to check what existing software is doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general approach is to convert an input sound into the sequence of feature vectors (usually, MFCCs). This process is described in general in [CMU Sphinx wiki](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialconcepts#recognition_process), and described in details in [HTK Book](http://speech.ee.ntu.edu.tw/homework/DSP_HW2-1/htkbook.pdf). You might also want to study the general-purpose [openSMILE toolkit](http://audeering.com/research/opensmile/) to see how it is done in C++.